# How do I change border color of a single table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to highlight a table row by changing the border color of that individual row. This is my CSS:

```
    table { border-collapse: collapse;}

    td { min-width: 100px; border: 1px solid green; }

    .highlight td { border: 1px solid orange; }
```

...and this is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result is this:
[image]

The top border remains green. The only way I could get it work was by changing border-bottom color of the TD elements 1 and 2. Is there a more elegant solution? Using the outline property didn't do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Only by removing `border-collapse: collapse;` because it merges borders that are adjacent.

Then apply a `0` value for `border-spacing`

[**Border-spacing : MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

> The border-spacing CSS property specifies the distance between the borders of adjacent table cells (only for the separated borders model). This is equivalent to the cellspacing attribute in presentational HTML, but an optional second value can be used to set different horizontal and vertical spacing.

```css
table {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size:32px;
}

td {
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.highlight td {
  border-color: orange;
}
/* optional enhancment to narrow vertical joined borders*/
td + td {
  border-left:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it does not do the trick, because it makes the borders thicker. I need the result to be exactly the same as shown in the image - except for the color of the top border. Never thought this could be so tricky.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
td { min-width: 100px;}
td:first-child{border-right: 1px solid green;}
tr{border: 1px solid green;}
tr.highlight td { border: 1px solid orange; border-top: 1px solid orange; }
```

you should give the border to the rows and the td that are first child, then apply different color for the border of the highlited tr.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this give your tr a `display` property of `block`. See the code snippet below.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
td {
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*
    Remove the left border from td
    to make the border width even
    on all sides.
  */
  border-left: none;
}
td:first-child {
  /*
    If the td is the first child
    give it a left border to close
    the left side of the row.
  */
    border-left: 1px solid green;
}
.highlight td {
  /*
    Since you're changing only the
    border-color, you only need to
    redefine the border-color.
  */
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you set the width of tr to 100%, which I have in the script, you can use `inline-block` or `inline-flex` for your `display` property.

```
/*
  In the case of the tr with a width of 100%
  all of the following have the same output
  for their borders.
*/
display: inline-block;
display: inline-flex;
display: block;
```